# React pass prop between components

Tags: reactjs

I have a problem during pass the data between two components.

```
const [ideas, setIdeas] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
    getIdeas();
  }, []);

  const getIdeas = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await axios.get(import.meta.env.VITE_APP_API_URL + `/api/v1/ideas`, { headers })
      setIdeas(res.data.data);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e)
    }
  }
```

After that in my rendering I create a control like this:

```
{ideas.length > 0 ? (
          <>
            {console.log(ideas)}
            <BasicTable data={ideas} />
          </>
        ) : (
          <div>Loading</div>
        )}
```

I can See the ideas values in my console.

Inside BasicTable Component I have something like this:

```
  export const BasicTable = ({ideas }) => {
     const columns = useMemo(() => COLUMNS, [])
     const data = useMemo(() => ideas, [])

     console.log(ideas)
     ...
```

my ideas is always undefined

Comment: the reason is you are passing data as a component

Comment: Typo?  You're passing a prop called `data` but expecting a prop called `ideas`.  The names need to match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Pass your ideas as prop rather data something like this in BasicTable comp.**

```js
<BasicTable ideas={ideas} />
```

Comment: Do not post answers to problems caused by typo type issues, or answer with **your code works**. These issues should be called out in comments and flagged, as there is a specific close flag **Not reproducible or was caused by a typo**. Please see [How do I handle "it's working" answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/348880/7758804). These questions are typically downvoted, closed and deleted, as they are of no benefit to the community.